# How to configure Laravael 4.2 Environment

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm new on Laravael and i've a website, developed by another dev and i need to migrate this website to another server.

For now, i'm testing the environment. This is my structure:
Testing (Local)
Staging (subdomaindomain.com for testing online)
Production (Domain.com)

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'testing' => array('localdomain.dev'),
    'staging' => array('develop.domain.com'),
    'production' => array('www.domain.com')
));
```

I've the correspondent folders, and files to overwrite the originals.

After this line, i make an echo $env and the result is always PRODUCTION either on local (domain.dev) either on staging (develop.domain.com)

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 4.1, environment detection only uses host names, *not* domains. To quote [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-4.1):

> **Environment Detection Updates**
>
> For security reasons, URL domains may no longer be used to detect your application environment. These values are easily spoofable and allow attackers to modify the environment for a request. You should convert your environment detection to use machine host names (`hostname` command on Mac, Linux, and Windows).

Instead of using the domain names of the various servers, you'll have to use the machine's host name.

---

If you don't know the machine's host name, try this:

```php
echo gethostname();
```

then use that in your environments array.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use hostnames, you can also set an environment variable in your web server virtual host config. For Apache: `SetEnv APP_ENV production`

And then:

```php
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    return getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'testing';
});
```